# jQuery click sort and reset not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following simple HTML markup:

```
<div class="sorter">
    <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
</div>
<div class="market-slider">
    <div class="market-search">
        <div class="market-inner-item" data-position="1"> .. </div>
        <div class="market-inner-item" data-position="2"> .. </div>
        <div class="market-inner-item" data-position="3"> .. </div>
        <div class="market-inner-item" data-position="4"> .. </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$('.sorter i.fa-sort').click(function(e) {
    $(".market-slider .market-inner-item").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.market-slider');
    function sort_li(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) > ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Problem: 
It works. It makes use of the HTML5 data attribute (e.g. data-position="4") to determine the order of the div. I want to be able to click on the sort button and have the result sort or appear in reverse order.

Simple English: I click - it sorts in descending). I click again - it sort in Asc (back to normal). I click again - the process repeats and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a counter

```
var elm = $('.sorter i.fa-sort');
elm.data("what", "sort")
elm.click(function(e) {
    if (elm.data("what") == "sort") {
        $(".market-slider .market-inner-item").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.market-slider');
        $(this).data("what", "reverse");
    } else {
        $(".market-slider .market-inner-item").sort(sort_li).reverse().appendTo('.market-slider');
        $(this).data("what", "sort");
    }
    function sort_li(a, b) {
        return ($(b).data('position')) > ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```